# My android studio 1.1.0 cannot seem to find my usb device

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I have my usb debugging turned on. I installed **google usb driver**. In the `androidmanifest.xml` i even typed

```
   android:debuggable="true".
```

I tried both MTP and PTP. My phone is **asus zenfone 5** running android lollipop i.e. API21.

Build tool version is 21.1.2.

I am new to programming. I don't have a clue on how to run it in my phone . Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are new to programming if you think Android has anything to do with Classic ASP!

Comment: Go to adb and type `adb devices` and tell the result

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, using Google USB Driver is meant for stock phones like Nexus 5, Nexus 6, and so on.

For Asus Zenfone 5 in your case, I highly recommend you to install ASUS drivers.

http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS%20ZenFone%205&p=39&s=1&os=32&hashedid=96nqlxHp1VKV4Rdz

You can find it here, under the USB section.